# SQL Group By and Inner Join syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, group-by, inner-join

```
SELECT t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB
FROM 
(
    SELECT t1.[KeyID], t1.[VaR], '383' AS DB FROM Table1 AS t1
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT t2.[KeyID], t2.[VaR], '55' AS DB FROM Table2 AS t2
)  AS t
INNER JOIN

(
    (
        SELECT t3.[KeyID], t3.[VaR] FROM Table1 AS t3
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT t4.[KeyID], t4.[VaR] FROM Table2 AS t4
    ) AS u
    GROUP BY u.KeyID, u.VaR
) ON t.KeyID=u.KeyID AND t.VaR=u.VaR

ORDER BY t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB;
```

When I run the above SQL statement in MS Access 2010 I get "SYntax error in JOIN operation". However, if I remove the "GROUP BY" clause the syntax runs fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps because your `GROUP BY` clause is in the wrong place? Try putting it immediately before the `ORDER BY`

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Either way, I am trying to group "u" and hence it should be inside the parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code must be work

```
SELECT t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB
FROM 
(
    SELECT t1.[KeyID], t1.[VaR], '383' AS DB FROM Table1 AS t1
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT t2.[KeyID], t2.[VaR], '55' AS DB FROM Table2 AS t2
)  AS t
INNER JOIN

(
    select * from
    (
        SELECT t3.[KeyID], t3.[VaR] FROM Table1 AS t3
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT t4.[KeyID], t4.[VaR] FROM Table2 AS t4
    ) AS u1
    GROUP BY u1.KeyID, u1.VaR
) as u ON t.KeyID=u.KeyID AND t.VaR=u.VaR

ORDER BY t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only `GROUP BY` the subject of a `SELECT`, so you'd need to add an additional `SELECT` clause to get this to work, I think. Something like:

```
SELECT t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB
FROM (
    SELECT t1.[KeyID], t1.[VaR], '383' AS DB FROM Table1 AS t1
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT t2.[KeyID], t2.[VaR], '55' AS DB FROM Table2 AS t2
)  AS t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT u.[KeyID], u.[VaR]
    FROM (
        SELECT t3.[KeyID], t3.[VaR] FROM Table1 AS t3
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT t4.[KeyID], t4.[VaR] FROM Table2 AS t4
    ) AS u
    GROUP BY u.KeyID, u.VaR
) ON t.KeyID=u.KeyID AND t.VaR=u.VaR
ORDER BY t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB;
```

Answer (score 1):

A `GROUP BY` is invalid without a corresponding `SELECT`. If you want your `GROUP BY` to apply to the result of the second `UNION ALL`, you need to use that result as a derived table – that is, you need to SELECT FROM it, then you will be able to apply a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB
FROM 
(
    SELECT t1.[KeyID], t1.[VaR], '383' AS DB FROM Table1 AS t1
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT t2.[KeyID], t2.[VaR], '55' AS DB FROM Table2 AS t2
)  AS t
INNER JOIN

(
    SELECT u.KeyID, u.VaR
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t3.[KeyID], t3.[VaR] FROM Table1 AS t3
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT t4.[KeyID], t4.[VaR] FROM Table2 AS t4
    ) AS u
    GROUP BY u.KeyID, u.VaR
) ON t.KeyID=u.KeyID AND t.VaR=u.VaR

ORDER BY t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB;
```

On the other hand, it seems you just want to eliminate duplicates from the combined set. In that case, you just need to replace that UNION ALL with a UNION:

```
SELECT t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB
FROM 
(
    SELECT t1.[KeyID], t1.[VaR], '383' AS DB FROM Table1 AS t1
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT t2.[KeyID], t2.[VaR], '55' AS DB FROM Table2 AS t2
)  AS t
INNER JOIN

    (
        SELECT t3.[KeyID], t3.[VaR] FROM Table1 AS t3
        UNION
        SELECT t4.[KeyID], t4.[VaR] FROM Table2 AS t4
    ) AS u
    ON t.KeyID=u.KeyID AND t.VaR=u.VaR

ORDER BY t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to compute but to me it looks like you are trying to group rows returned by the result of t3 UNION t4. In that case you can try the following:

```
SELECT t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB
FROM 
(
    SELECT t1.[KeyID], t1.[VaR], '383' AS DB FROM Table1 AS t1
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT t2.[KeyID], t2.[VaR], '55' AS DB FROM Table2 AS t2
)  AS t
INNER JOIN

(
    (

SELECT KeyID, VaR
FROM
(
        SELECT t3.[KeyID], t3.[VaR] FROM Table1 AS t3
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT t4.[KeyID], t4.[VaR] FROM Table2 AS t4
)
GROUP BY KeyID, VaR
    ) AS u


) ON t.KeyID=u.KeyID AND t.VaR=u.VaR

ORDER BY t.KeyID, t.VaR, t.DB;
```